# Why does InGen from Jurassic Park limit themselves to reviving only Mesozoic animals?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

They brought back dinosaurs obviously, Pterosaurs, even Mosasaurs. Why not bring back extinct creatures from other eras of time like mammoths, saber tooths, terror birds,  gorgonopsians, etc..?

Really, there are so many cool creatures they are neglecting in favor of creating dangerous hybrids for the sake of innovation.

Answer (score 7):

Because dinosaurs are cooler? Let's be honest, if you have to decide between a Smilodon and a Tyrannosaurus, which would you prefer? Sure, the Smilodon is an incredible creature as well, but it's still a big lion-like creature with some giant fangs, so similar to something you would see in a zoo. The same goes for mammoths (giant woolly elephant) and terror birds (big flesh-eating ostrich) as well.
The main reason behind the creation of the Indominus Rex, the first hybrid was that after so many years people began to get "bored" of the dinosaurs. The wow! factor was gone, they became a common thing.

> CLAIRE: We've been pre-booking tickets for months. The park needs a new attraction every few years in order to reinvigorate the public's interest. Kind of like the space program. Corporate felt genetic modification would up the "wow" factor.
>
> OWEN: They're dinosaurs. "Wow" enough.
>
> CLAIRE: Not according to our focus groups. The Indominus rex makes us relevant again.

Now imagine this if they cloned prehistoric mammals. This would happen much faster with them, meaning less visitors to the park.

Comment: You are forgetting that elephants are highly intelligent beings whose intelligence level might possibly be equal to that of humans - in short elephants might possibly be people.  Furthermore, at least 15 species of prehistoric elephants became extinct in the last 13,000 years, possibly due in part to hunting by humans. So some people might claim that humans have an ethical duty to revive extinct species of elephants.

Comment: That's a valid point, but then this would be a self generating cycle, because where would you stop? First let's say "modern day", then prehistoric animals hunted by humans, but what's next? The neanderthals? It is assumed that the modern human played a big role in their extinction. 
The neanderthal may not be as intelligent as modern humans, but they're intelligent in their own ways, so it would probably raise ethical questions regarding them, like can you put them in a zoo, or release them into public? (Actually I read a short story a few years ago, which was about this exactly.)

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Why would you think that the greedy corporate overlords of a theme park would be thinking anywhere along those lines?

Answer (score 6):

To "bring a creature back", you have to have its DNA. Don't forget, Jurassic Park was first made possible due to finding a mosquito, preserved in amber, still with the blood of various species of dinosaur. InGen (and anyone else using that method) are limited to the DNA they can extract from the preserved specimens.

Comment: Lots of mosquitoes. IGen bought massive quantities of amber to find as many as possible. The in-universe source of dino-DNA is applicable to any extinct species.

Comment: @Jontia Trilobites? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

InGen has recently taken to reviving non-mesozoic extinct species as well. A saber-tooth tiger makes an appearance in the upcoming 4th season of Camp Cretaceous.

Comment: That begs the question of why InGen waited until recently to do that.

Answer (score -1):

As to why they didn't revive mammoths and saber tooths, these animals need a colder climate. They can't live on the too warm Isla Nublar and Isla Sorna.

Other than these, who says Mr. Hammond didn't revive or try to revive other Antediluvian animals we don't see in the movies? Dr. Ellie Sattler recognizes first that there she picked up an extinct plant, and the entire Isla Nublar and Isla Sorna look Antediluvian. But it's too warm for certain extinct animals to survive there. But maybe with a changed mammoth DNA the scientists would manage even that, though it would look weird. Mr. Hammond told the first visitors that more attractions would eventually come.

Since Mr. Hammond tried to recreate an Antediluvian environment, certain postdiluvian but extinct species (such as Dodos or the Great Auk) wouldn't fit there either.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by antediluvian and postdiluvian. Can you explain?

Comment: @Shadi Antediluvian means 'pre-Flood', before the global flood that God sent upon the Earth when Noah, his family and a pair of each animal were saved on Noah's ark. The flood lasted one year until Noah's ark landed in the mountains of Ararat (eastern Turkey). Of course, InGen couldn't recreate a perfectly pre-Flood environment because the atmosphere was a bit different in the Antediluvian era, such as more oxygen. But what it managed was very good and very close, dare I say.